# Pandas count, sum, average specific range/ value for each row

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, isin

i have big data, i want to count, sum, average for each row only between specific range.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id0':[10.3,20,30,50,108,110],'id1':[100.5,0,300,570,400,140], 'id2':[-2.6,-3,5,12,44,53], 'id3':[-100.1,4,6,22,12,42]})
```

> ```
>      id0    id1   id2    id3
> 0   10.3  100.5  -2.6 -100.1
> 1   20.0    0.0  -3.0    4.0
> 2   30.0  300.0   5.0    6.0
> 3   50.0  570.0  12.0   22.0
> 4  108.0  400.0  44.0   12.0
> 5  110.0  140.0  53.0   42.0
> ```

for example i want to count the occurrence of value between 10-100 for each row, so it will get:

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    3
4    2
5    2
Name: count_10-100, dtype: int64
```

currently i get this done by iterate for each row, transverse and using groupby. But this take a time because i have ~500 column and 500000 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the conditions with AND between them, and then `sum` along the row (axis 1):

```
((df >= 10) & (df <= 100)).sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    3
4    2
5    2
dtype: int64
```

---

For sum and mean, you can apply the conditions with `where`:

```
df.where((df >= 10) & (df <= 100)).sum(axis=1)
df.where((df >= 10) & (df <= 100)).mean(axis=1)
```

Credit for this goes to @anky, who posted it first as a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Below summarizes the different situations in which you'd want to count something in a DataFrame (or Series, for completeness), along with the recommended method(s).

`DataFrame.count` returns counts for each column as a Series since the non-null count varies by column.
`DataFrameGroupBy.size` returns a Series, since all columns in the same group share the same row-count.
`DataFrameGroupBy.count` returns a DataFrame, since the non-null count could differ across columns in the same group.
To get the group-wise non-null count for a specific column, use `df.groupby(...)['x'].count()` where "x" is the column to count.

#Code Examples

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': list('aabbc'), 'B': ['x', 'x', np.nan, 'x', np.nan]})
s = df['B'].copy()

df

   A    B
0  a    x
1  a    x
2  b  NaN
3  b    x
4  c  NaN

s

0      x
1      x
2    NaN
3      x
4    NaN
Name: B, dtype: object
Row Count of a DataFrame: len(df), df.shape[0], or len(df.index)
len(df)
# 5

df.shape[0]
# 5

len(df.index)
# 5
```

Of the three methods above, len(df.index) (as mentioned in other answers) is the fastest.

Note

All the methods above are constant time operations as they are simple attribute lookups.
df.shape (similar to ndarray.shape) is an attribute that returns a tuple of (# Rows, # Cols).

Column Count of a DataFrame: df.shape[1], len(df.columns)

```
df.shape[1]
# 2

len(df.columns)
# 2
```

Analogous to len(df.index), len(df.columns) is the faster of the two methods (but takes more characters to type).

Row Count of a Series:

```
len(s), s.size, len(s.index)

len(s)
# 5

s.size
# 5

len(s.index)
# 5
```

s.size and len(s.index) are about the same in terms of speed. But I recommend len(df).

size is an attribute, and it returns the number of elements (=count of rows for any Series). DataFrames also define a size attribute which returns the same result as

```
df.shape[0] * df.shape[1].
```

Non-Null Row Count: DataFrame.count and Series.count
The methods described here only count non-null values (meaning NaNs are ignored).

Calling DataFrame.count will return non-NaN counts for each column:

```
df.count()

A    5
B    3
dtype: int64
For Series, use Series.count to similar effect:

s.count()
# 3
```

Group-wise Row Count: GroupBy.size
For DataFrames, use DataFrameGroupBy.size to count the number of rows per group.

```
df.groupby('A').size()

A
a    2
b    2
c    1
dtype: int64
```

Similarly, for Series, you'll use SeriesGroupBy.size.

```
s.groupby(df.A).size()

A
a    2
b    2
c    1
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

In both cases, a Series is returned.

Group-wise Non-Null Row Count: GroupBy.count
Similar to above, but use GroupBy.count, not GroupBy.size. Note that size always returns a Series, while count returns a Series if called on a specific column, or else a DataFrame.

The following methods return the same thing:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].size()
df.groupby('A').size()

A
a    2
b    2
c    1
Name: B, dtype: int64



df.groupby('A').count()

   B
A
a  2
b  1
c  0



df.groupby('A')['B'].count()

A
a    2
b    1
c    0
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a neat way to do that with aggregations and using pandas methods. It can be read as "aggregate by row (axis=1) where x is greater or equal to 10 and less or equal to 100".

```
df.agg(lambda x : (x.ge(10) & x.le(100)).sum(), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will help you.

```
df["n_values_in_range"] = df.apply(
    func=lambda row: count_values_in_range(row, range_min, range_max), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.between(10, 100), axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    3
4    2
5    2
```